# Confused about libc conflicts in cross compilation in Github actions linux runner using cargo cross

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rust, github-actions, cross-compiling

I'm trying to cross compile my Rust application to `aarch64` in Github Actions runner using `cargo cross`. More specifically this is the excerpt which does it.

```yaml
      - name: Build binary
        uses: houseabsolute/actions-rust-cross@v0
        with:
          command: "build"
          target: ${{ matrix.platform.target }}
          toolchain: ${{ matrix.toolchain }}
          args: "--locked --release"
          strip: true
        env:
          # Build environment variables
          GITHUB_ENV: ${{ github.workspace }}/.env
```

This runs `cross build` in the background and for the scope of the question we can keep the target as `aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu`.

`cargo cross` uses containers to do the compilation. For this target it'd probably use this image. https://github.com/cross-rs/cross/blob/main/docker/Dockerfile.aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu

You can extend the images also. This is what I do because my application depends on external libraries such as `libasound2-dev` and `libjack-jackd2-dev`.

Here is how I extend it,

```
ARG CROSS_BASE_IMAGE
FROM $CROSS_BASE_IMAGE

ARG CROSS_DEB_ARCH
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Update and upgrade the base system
RUN apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get upgrade -y \
    && apt-get dist-upgrade -y

# Install aptitude for more robust dependency resolution
RUN apt-get install -y aptitude

# Add sources for the specified architecture
RUN if echo "$CROSS_DEB_ARCH" | grep -q "arm"; then \
    echo "deb [arch=$CROSS_DEB_ARCH] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ focal main restricted universe multiverse" > /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    echo "deb [arch=$CROSS_DEB_ARCH] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    echo "deb [arch=$CROSS_DEB_ARCH] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    echo "deb [arch=$CROSS_DEB_ARCH] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list; \
    else \
    echo "deb [arch=$CROSS_DEB_ARCH] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted universe multiverse" > /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    echo "deb [arch=$CROSS_DEB_ARCH] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    echo "deb [arch=$CROSS_DEB_ARCH] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    echo "deb [arch=$CROSS_DEB_ARCH] http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list; \
    fi

RUN dpkg --add-architecture ${CROSS_DEB_ARCH} && apt-get update -y

# Install build dependencies
RUN aptitude install -y libasound2-dev:${CROSS_DEB_ARCH} libjack-jackd2-dev:${CROSS_DEB_ARCH}
```

This basically results with

```
#10 5.106 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
#10 5.106  libc6:arm64 : Breaks: libc6 (!= 2.31-0ubuntu9.12) but 2.23-0ubuntu11.3 is installed.
#10 5.106  libc6 : Breaks: libc6:arm64 (!= 2.23-0ubuntu11.3) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.12 is to be installed.
#10 5.106  libcrypt1:arm64 : Breaks: libc6 (< 2.31) but 2.23-0ubuntu11.3 is installed.
#10 5.106  libstdc++6:arm64 : Breaks: libstdc++6 (!= 10.5.0-1ubuntu1~20.04) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12 is installed.
#10 5.106  libstdc++6 : Breaks: libstdc++6:arm64 (!= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) but 10.5.0-1ubuntu1~20.04 is to be installed.
#10 5.106 The following actions will resolve these dependencies:
#10 5.106 
#10 5.106       Keep the following packages at their current version:
#10 5.106 1)      libasound2:arm64 [Not Installed]                   
#10 5.106 2)      libasound2-dev:arm64 [Not Installed]               
#10 5.106 3)      libc6:arm64 [Not Installed]                        
#10 5.106 4)      libcrypt1:arm64 [Not Installed]                    
#10 5.106 5)      libgcc-s1:arm64 [Not Installed]                    
#10 5.106 6)      libidn2-0:arm64 [Not Installed]                    
#10 5.106 7)      libjack-jackd2-0:arm64 [Not Installed]             
#10 5.106 8)      libjack-jackd2-dev:arm64 [Not Installed]           
#10 5.106 9)      libsamplerate0:arm64 [Not Installed]               
#10 5.106 10)     libstdc++6:arm64 [Not Installed]                   
#10 5.106 11)     libunistring2:arm64 [Not Installed]                
#10 5.106 
#10 5.106 
#10 5.106 
#10 5.715 No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
```

I decrypt this as there is a dependency conflict regarding `libc6` but from there on I tend to loose the context.

`libasound2` and/or `libjack-jackd2-dev` as packages I guess pre built with a certain version of `libc`.

The image that I use have a version of `libc`.

Are they the ones which are conflicting?
Could you help me to understand the core of this problem or even better how to resolve it?
I can't say that I'm very familiar with cross compilation especially in linux environment and ubuntu's package ecosystem.

Comment: Actually I've resolved it, I'll write an answer soon.